# Matrix multiplication to mirror translation and rotation of only 1 axis?

Tags: opengl, matrix, graphics, matrix-multiplication

I'm using OpenGL with some other library. This library will provide Projection Matrix and I cannot modify it. I have to provide only ModelViewMatrix.

However, strange things happen. Only y-axis translation and rotation are inverted.

For example if I increase x translation in the ModelViewMatrix then the object will go to the right just fine. (positive x direction) but in y-axis it is reversed. I want it to go the other way.

Rotation in y-axis also got reversed. It is rotation opposite of the way it should be.

I cannot fix it on ProjectionMatrix, so I think I might have to multiply my ModelViewMatrix with something that can reverse one axis before send it to the library. Do you know that something? A matrix that can reverse 1 axis?

Answer (score 1):

it's just a matrix with elements `[1,0,0,0][0,-1,0,0][0,0,1,0][0,0,0,1]`

in other words an identity matrix with the second diagonal element negated.

Comment: Note that this will create a "mirror image" of the original (mirrored using the XZ plane, the same as doing scale(1,-1,1)). If the model has reversed Y coordinates, that's fine, but if it's only the camera that is on the wrong side, a 180 degree rotation might be needed instead.